# query params dependent on other query params in hapi-swagger

Tags: swagger, hapi.js, hapi-swagger

I am building a hapi-swagger interface to my api. One of the query params, *type*, has another query param *subtype* that depends on the former. I have figured out how to implement `Joi` [validation for it successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582834/validating-sub-params-dependent-on-parent-params-with-joi-and-hapi) but am not so successful with the interface. My validation code is

```
{
    type: Joi.string()
         .valid('image', 'publication', 'dataset')
         .optional(),

    subtype: Joi.string()
         .optional()
         .when('type', {is: 'image',       then: Joi.valid('png', 'jpg')})
         .when('type', {is: 'publication', then: Joi.valid('newspaper', 'book')})
         .description('subtype based on the file_type')
}
```

But the interface shows only **png** and **jpg** for *subtype*. Suggestions on how I could implement this so the correct *subtype* shows when the respective *type* is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar and it works fine for me. Please checkout my code below:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  billFormat: Joi.string().valid('sms', 'email').required(),
  email: Joi.string()
    .when('ebillFormat', { is: 'sms', then: Joi.valid('a', 'b') })
    .when('ebillFormat', { is: 'email', then: Joi.valid('c', 'd') }),
});
```

And my payload looks like below:

```
{
    "ebillFormat": "email",
    "email": "hello"
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "child \"email\" fails because [\"email\" must be one of [c, d]]",
    "validation": {
        "source": "payload",
        "keys": [
            "email"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please let me know what exactly you are trying to achieve and what issue are you facing.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question about, I to am able to do the validation successfully. Where I am failing (or rather, the `hapi-swagger` module is failing), is in building the interface correctly. So, I guess this is more of a `hapi-swagger` question rather than a `Joi` question. Specifically, in my case, the dropdown menu for **subtype** shows only *png* and *jpg* as options.

Comment: oh now I get your issues. According to me its somewhat related to the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/33#issuecomment-180465799)